# Visual Studio .vs folder does not appear anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2017

So I am using visual studio with a big web app, I remember every time I would launch it, there was a .vs folder that would contain an applicationhost.config file in which I would modify the allowedServerVariables property.

for some reason, I don't see that folder anymore... I don't know if a Visual Studio setting, or just a display property (I remember the folder was like kind of transparent)

But the one sure thing is that I haven't changed anything in the code. Is there a way that this is linked to a setting in Visual Studio?

Comment: .vs is typically a hidden folder.  Have you made sure, you are not simply, hiding hidden folders?

Comment: I have been stuck on this for hours... thanks Ramhound... I can't believe I didn't check that lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see that folder anymore...

The `.vs` folder is typically hidden by default. Change your File Explorer settings to view hidden files.